# How to write a "bash script.sh argument "

Tags: linux, bash

hi can someone help me with this.

How to Write a script that takes in as argument a filename and displays its modification date and time in this way exactly :

```
[user@localhost...]$ bash script.sh temp.txt
the file temp.txt was modified on May 1 20:20
```

And then modify that script in such a way that it lists the modification dates for directories whose names contain a given pattern in this way exactly :

```
[user@local....]$ bash script.sh testRegex Pub
the file testRegex was modified on May 1 20:22
the directory /home/user/Public was modified on Dec 26 08:00
the directory /home/user/Pubs. was modified on May 2 20:00
```

please help I need to answer this fast

Thanks

Comment: We will not do your homework for you, and it's unclear what, exactly, you're stuck on.  But perhaps it would help you to have a look at the [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Your comment below to one of the answers is kind of humorous: *"thanks but I really cant make much with this, the due date is in 2 days and I haven't been attending this course but I'm trying to understand as much as I can and work with it but I got stuck with this. any simpler help will really means a lot."*. We really need a ***Give Mez The Codez*** stack exchange for folks like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do actually. You should read up on the [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command as @John Bollinger said. I also used the [date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command to format the date. You can read up on taking arguments for a script [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script)

Combining all of this would give -

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1;
dirname=$2;

file_mod_date=`date -d @$( stat -c %Y $1 ) +%m" "%B" "%H:%M`;

echo "The file ${filename} was modified on ${file_mod_date}";
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
    exit 1;
else
for i in /home/user/*${dirname}*/; do
    dir_mod_date=`date -d @$( stat -c %Y $i ) +%m" "%B" "%H:%M`;
    echo "The directory ${i} was modified on ${dir_mod_date}";
done
fi
```

Comment: Lol you shouldn’t have done the work then

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is with passing options and values:

For example:

```
file_name=""
help_message="To use this script type script.sh --file /path/to/file.txt"
# -- Get input options (if any)
while [[ $# > 0 ]] ;do
    key="$1"
    case ${key,,} in
        -f|--file)
            file_name="${2,,}"
            shift
        ;;
        -h|--help)
            echo -e "$help_message"
            exit;
            shift
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Call the script like this:

```
bash script.sh -f "temp.txt"
```

With regard to the "logic" of the script, you will have to figure that out ;-)